# How to programmatically add/remove an image to navigation bar title in Swift 3/Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uiimage

So I currently have a menu bar open and close on the left side of the app, and I want a certain image to appear on the navigation bar title when I open the menu. Below is my function for opening and closing the menu.

```
@IBAction func openMenu(_ sender: Any) {

    if (menuShowing) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.20, blue:0.63, alpha:1.0)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationItem.titleView = ""
        leadingConstraint.constant = -240
        shadowLeadingConstraint.constant = -250
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

    }
    else {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.20, blue:0.63, alpha:1.0)

        let image = UIImage(named: "MenuBarTransparent")
        navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
        navigationItem.titleView?.frame=CGRect(x:10, y:0, width:30, height:360)

        leadingConstraint.constant = 0
        shadowLeadingConstraint.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
    menuShowing = !menuShowing
}
```

This portion of code in the above function makes the image appear when I want it to, but manipulating the x and y-coordinate has no effect whatsoever so I can't center the image correctly:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "MenuBarTransparent")
        navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
        navigationItem.titleView?.frame=CGRect(x:10, y:0, width:30,  height:360)
```

Also, this portion of code from above does not let me delete the image from the nav bar title whenever I close the menu again, it says "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UIView?':

```
navigationItem.titleView = ""
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a string to the title view. Instead of `navigationItem.titleView = ""` , I think you should use `navigationItem.titleView = nil`.

Comment: Ah! Perfect. This actually helps solve two problems I had, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would set the object with it's init.

navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView.init(image: UIImage(named:"image"))

Comment: This makes my image show up correctly, but it's almost like my x and y coordinate as well as the width are fixed. I can change the height of the image as much as I want and can see it update when I change it, but nothing else responds.

Comment: You can just reset those values to what you want in the init, rather than after it's been instantiated